# Construct regex pattern does not match for given invalid input in java

Tags: java, regex

I am constructing regex pattern for Android identifiers. Android identifiers should be in the following format as,

```
<8 character alphaNumeric>-<4 character alphaNumeric>-<4 character alphaNumeric>-<12 character alphaNumeric>
```

Sample android id is,

```
5f302bf7-97ad-4c24-86f5-823f881d954e
```

So, to match an above format my regex pattern look like,

```
"^([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}\\" + "-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}\\" + "-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}\\"
```

If I gave an invalid Android identifies as,

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

which also matches the above regex pattern.

How to construct regex pattern which doesn't match for above invalid identifiers?

Comment: Did you use `String#matches()`? I'd assume not since otherwise your pattern wouldn't match. Besides that, your pattern matches the first 3 groups only, i.e. `00000000-0000-0000`. That 12 character sequence is missing. Besides that, why did you add those slashes and why did you concatenate strings instead of creating the pattern in one string?

Comment: please provide an [mcve]

Comment: Having a second look at your pattern I strongly agree with Jens: your pattern isn't even complete so unless you provide the complete relevant portions of your code (aka [mcve]) the only thing we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you correctly, you want to validate an identifier which has the following rules

- It should allow hexadecimal characters only (0-9, a-f and A-F)
- It should be 28 characters long and separated by dashes (-) and of the structure {8 characters}-{4 characters}-{4 characters}-{12 characters}

Regex: `^[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}$`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MFPoY6/1)

Matches:

```
FF000000-0000-0000-0000ABCDEF0A
00000000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Rejects:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
00000000 0000 0000 0000 000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000-0000-0000-00000000000G
```

Comment: I don't want pattern to match this "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000". Because its an invalid identifier.

Comment: So what is _a valid identifier_? Can you share an example?

Comment: "FF000000-0000-0000-0000ABCDEF0A" is a valid identifier. And "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000" it is not. But above pattern would accept both.